# Spring isUserInRole dont work with role from MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My Spring Application use a database with user and role and crosstable of both for my login page.

To redirect the users to different role pages i use a controller

```
@Controller
public class StartController {
    @RequestMapping("/default")
    public String defaultAfterLogin(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.isUserInRole("ADMIN")) {
            return "redirect:/admin/";
        }
        return "redirect:/user/";
    }
}
```

But i try it with the user "admin" and i get the redirect to `/user`

Print out `request.getUserPrincipal().toString()`:

```
Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@79225df7:
Username: admin@test.de; 
Password: [PROTECTED]; 
Enabled: true; 
AccountNonExpired: true; 
credentialsNonExpired: true; 
AccountNonLocked: true; 
Granted Authorities: ADMIN; 
Credentials: [PROTECTED]; 
Authenticated: true; 
Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364:
RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; 
SessionId: null; 
Granted Authorities: ADMIN
```

What is the Problem for the redirect to `/admin` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try with this instead :

```
boolean hasAuthorityAdmin = false;

hasAuthorityAdmin = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().contains(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN);
if (hasAuthorityAdmin) {
    return "redirect:/admin/";
}
return "redirect:/user/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a loadUserAuthorities Custom ....and you migrated to spring 4 from spring 3 ..........by this reason you have to add prefix ROLE_ in your list from database  from loadUserAuthorities  beacause 
request.isUserInRole("ADMIN") comvert to ROLE_ADMIN  and compare with your list